# Serve Static Files using warp in rust

Tags: web-applications, rust, rust-warp

I am using `warp` library to make a web app in rust. I am trying to serve the static files.
I have read its documentation from [Doc](https://docs.rs/warp/0.2.0/warp/filters/fs/fn.dir.html).

**Here is my code snippet**

```
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde::Serialize;
use warp::path;
use warp::Filter;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let static_assets = warp::path("static").and(warp::fs::dir("/www/static"));

    // let routes = get_routes.or(post_routes).or(static_assets).or(file_route);
    let routes = static_assets;

    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)).await;
}
```

But When I visit the path `localhost:3030/static/index.js`, it gives back the `404` response

**Here is the file tree**

```
src
├── main.rs
└── www
    └── static
        └── index.js
```

Answer (score 8):

The error here was surprisingly trivial. The path `/www/static` is absolute. For it to work, you'll have to have that directory at the root of your file system. By using relative path, it works:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let route = warp::path("static").and(warp::fs::dir("www/static"));

    warp::serve(route).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)).await;
}
```