# How to redirect to URL with trailing slash in warp?

Tags: rust, routes, webserver, url-routing, rust-warp

I am using [`warp`](https://crates.io/crates/warp) to serve a directory of static files. Unfortunately the relative links used in those static files can only be resolved, when I add a trailing slash to my path.

This is the code I use to serve the directory:

```rust
let route = warp::path("segment")
    .and(warp::path("another"))
    .and(warp::fs::dir("../path/to/static/files/folder"));
warp::serve(route).run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 3030)).await;
```

So now

- `0.0.0.0:3030/segment/another/` works fine
- `0.0.0.0:3030/segment/another` does not work

In principle I would not mind this and just always use the URLs with trailing slashes, however when I "Add to Homescreen" the page from Safari on iOS (as a PWA) the trailing slash is ommited automatically.

So in order to work around this, I tried to create a redirect, and then add the trailing slash like this:

```rust
let redirect = warp::path("segment").and(warp::path("another")).and(warp::path::end())
.map(|| {
    warp::redirect(Uri::from_static("0.0.0.0:3030/segment/another/"))
});
```

however this redirect filter only matches `0.0.0.0:3030/segment/another/`. When I omit the `warp::path::end()` the redirect works for `0.0.0.0:3030/segment/another` but now everything (for example `0.0.0.0:3030/segment/another/styles.css`) gets redirected to `0.0.0.0:3030/segment/another/`.

Is there a way to only redirect when the path does not end with a slash or a file extension (e.g. `.html`, `.css`etc.)?

It might be that my overall aproach is incorrect here, too.

Comment: This thread can be useful: https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/issues/584